# Change status (accept/decline) of job message

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

After accidentally clicking "I'm interested" in the notification email for a job offer, I'm unable to change the status to "I'm not interested".

When clicking on the "I'm not interested" link in the notification email, I see an error message:

> You've already responded to this job.

It would be great if users could change this status after setting another one.